# How to add a custom attribute to the HTML output of rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

With rails version 2.3.8 I'm trying to get HTML output like:

```
    <a href="/product/list" data-role="button">Product list</a>
```

So an A tag with a custom attribute "data-role". (The reason I want the "data-role" attribute is that I'm working with [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) which picks up on this attribute and does its magic) So I was trying to do this

```
    <%= link_to "product list", :controller => "product", :action => "list", "data-role" => "button" %>
```

Judging by [this tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/getting-started-with-jquery-mobile-rails-3/) perhaps this would work in rails 3, but in rails 2.3.8 it interprets it by generating a data-role=button parameter on the link URL.

One way I can get the desired HTML output is to use url_for instead:

```
    <a href="<%=url_for :controller =>"product", :action => "list" %>" data-role="button">Product list</a>
```

A bit long and ugly. Is there a way to make link_to output custom attributes in the A tag (?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to "product list", { :controller => "product", :action => "list" }, "data-role" => "button" %>
```

Comment: Would be nice to find a way to alter link_to to always generate links w/ a button data-role

Comment: i'm too late, but now you can use rails html helpers for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use fancybox in **link_to** on rails.

```
<%= link_to image_path('website/website_new/apps/filter_2.png'),"data-fancybox"  => "images" do %>
  <%= image_tag "website/website_new/apps/filter_2.png", class:"image-medium inline-block cast-shadow" %>
<% end %>
```

**Output:**

```
<a data-fancybox="images" href="/assets/website/website_new/apps/filter_1-d6e69e3728465146276c548645b649be.png"><img class="image-medium inline-block cast-shadow" src="/assets/website/website_new/apps/filter_1-d6e69e3728465146276c548645b649be.png" alt="Filter 1"></a>
```